# How to specify path for upload and export features in Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-devops

Below are code snippets of what I currently use to import and export Excel files. However, is it possible to make this work through an Azure Web App which is serverless?

C#

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\report.xlsx", excel.GetAsByteArray());
```

SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, Salary)
SELECT FirstName, Salary
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Temp\Data.xlsx', [Sheet1$]);
```

[image]

Comment: You have a hanging `END` :)

Comment: How do you perform them in Azure? Create an Azure VM and run it in there? I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid What if I’m using the AppServices for website (not VM)?

Comment: Ah OK I see now. You'd need to use blob storage instead of file paths

Comment: There's a whole bunch of security and network stuff to set up first. But look at what you're doing.... you're doing an excel export of data via a web page. There are other ways to do that that don't require dodgy tricks like this

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1:**

This could be achieved using azure logics apps along with web apps.

1. [Logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) are a server less offering from azure where you can create workflows combining different steps like connecting to database, extracting / exporting data to CSV or Excel file, upload file to blob storage or an ftp location or send it as attachment in email. You can follow steps [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-automation-export-azure-sql-database-data-to-csv-files-using-azure-logic-apps/) to create logic app.
2. But you want to access this using azure web app. That's also possible using https request from web app to trigger the logic apps. How part is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption).
3. Once the data is uploaded into blob storage, you can return the file link as response to the caller.

**Approach 2:**

Another way to achieve this is by coding data extract and upload logic at db end in a stored procedure. However, your db should be either on-prem or on IAAS ( VM based ) to be able to use xp_cmdshell utility from stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to map a network drive to an Azure file share. See here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/mapping-a-network-drive-to-an-azure-file-share-using-domain/ba-p/2220773